# Getting just one value from the array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I was able to get an array, but now I need to get only one value `[type]` the one that says `[type] => charge.succeeded`. Would it be something like `$type = $value[0]['type'];`? I want to use it as

```
    if ($type == "charge.succeeded") { echo "Do something" };
```

```
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {

    print_r($input);
}
```

=

```
Array
(
    [created] => 1326853478
    [livemode] => 
    [id] => charge.succeeded_00000000000000
    [type] => charge.succeeded
    [object] => event
    [request] => 
    [pending_webhooks] => 1
    [api_version] => 2018-10-31
    [data] => Array
)
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: why `[0]` ???? ?

Comment: You are almost there. Try focusing on `$key`. Good luck

Comment: Why you use a foreach loop to find type?  echo $input['type'] gives you charge.succeeded

Comment: Please try `$type = $value['type'];` instead of `$type = $value[0]['type'];` inside of `foreach`.

Comment: @Sfili_81 Yep, $input['type'] is working just like it should. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an associative array, meaning that the keys of the array can be anything. To get a value of this array, you should use the key directly on the array. In this case:

```
print_r($input['type']);
```

It's sort of the same thing as a map in other languages.

Comment: Not sort of, Arrays in PHP *are* ordered maps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (isset($input['type']) && $input['type'] === "charge.succeeded") {
    echo "Do something";
}
```

Instead of:

```
foreach($input as $key=>$value){
    print_r($input);
}
```

Comment: Should I use it inside the foreach or outside?

Comment: Without foreach. Use this instead of `foreach($input as $key=>$value){}`